# Got a iPhone/ a pc without iTunes/WiFi - Needs to transfer files from iPhone to pc. How?

Tags: file-transfer

Like the title says 
Got a iPhone/ a pc (w10) without iTunes/WiFi- need to transfer files (photos,zip,exe) from iPhone to pc. How?

Got usb cable and acces to WiFi on phone.

Would be very grateful if someone come up with something. I’ can’t find a solution

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Where are the zip and exe files stored on your iPhone? Specifically, under which app(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to transfer your photos to the pc. The charging cable serves both as a charging cable and a data transfer cable.  Disconnect the cable from the power adapter.  Plug the usb end into your computer.  Plug the other end into your phone. You should see the phone as a new device. It will appear as a photo card. You need to drill down until you see your photos.

Security restrictions have gotten tighter on the iPhone over time.  You can try 
https://macroplant.com/iexplorer for the other file types.

Comment: It's not that easy, at least not with my set-up which is an iPhone XR and a Win 7 Pro PC. The PC doesnt see the iPhone as a new device as soon as that cable is connected. I wish it did!

Comment: I guess Apple is trying to make the Windows environment as complicated as the Mac environment.  Try iTunes and iExplorer.